# Is it possible to get the latest commit in Github Repo to test in your local machine?

Tags: git, github, repository, branching-and-merging, collaboration

I am learning git and I am developing a small app with it. On my `Github` repository I have two branches (`master` and `contributions`) and two contributors. The `master` branch is for release phase and the `contribution` branch is for development and testing. Me and my team commit codes on `contribution` branch. Our problem is that when we wanted to test each other's contribution (codes), we don't how to do it well. We tried `pull`, `pull requests` and `merging/rebase` but I think it's not working the way we wanted it to be. We wanted to get the copies of all the commits of our team members to be tested on our local machines. We are developing a web app using `laravel framework` and as usual we are testing/running the app on our `localhost`. The problem is that we don't know if it is possible to get those commits and update our branches with the changes and without changing the architecture or structure of our `master` branch. Can someone please enlighten us if how we could actually do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you `pull` from your repository you will always get the latest version of your project. However you can also specify to get specific commit but you need it's commit id. Whenever you `push` project changes to your repository anybody who knows the address of your repository and have access to it can get the project files by using `pull` no matter what computer you are using.

Make sure that you both are pushing to the same branch that is `master`.

How you wanted it to work? If you get error message please provide it here.

Comment: Yes, this `pull` works. My bad because I did not commit my latest changes on the app that's why I can't `pull`. By the way thank you for your upfront enlightenment.

Comment: You're welcome :) Remember to mark this question as answered.